# How to fix Error: 'YoShop_Direct_Checkout' does not have a method 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect'

Tags: php, wordpress

i have in my log error file this error:

```
[Tue May 02 12:16:06 2017] [error] [client 46.**.88.4] PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'YoShop_Direct_Checkout' does not have a method 'custom_add_to_cart_redirect' in /var/www/clients/client1/web35/web/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 235, referer: http://domain.###/
```

This is making my website slow, and buggy , how i can fix it?
PS: if i stop the plugin, i cant skip the add cart - so when the users buy anything by clicking on a button like this one :

```
<a href="/checkout/?product_id=4357&amp;quantity=1" rel="attachment wp-att-542"><img style="border-radius: 10px; max-width: 950px !important; text-align: center !important;" src="http://domain.###/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/pic.jpg" alt=""></a>
```

they should be redirected to the checkout woocommerce page, not to the cart page.

Can you please help me?

( i saw here a similar question with no answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42901778/woocommerce-error-does-not-have-a-method-custom-add-to-cart-redirect )

(also i did try all the other available plugins at the moment (02.05.2017), and nothing worked :( ).

May be i need to paste some code in my finctions.php file?
Or i dont know - please help me.

I am sure this will help a lot of people, cos i found many many questions about it in the internet - with zero answers ........
Thanks in advance guys !

Best Regards: /P. Rashkov/